# Add custom select dropdown in magento grid

Tags: php, magento, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a custom dropdown with (select/options) in my magento grid but it doesn't work, I tried with

```
$this->addColumn('dropdown', array(
'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Dropdown'),
'filter'    => false,
'sortable'  => false,
'type'=> 'options',
'options' => array('First'=>'firstvalue', 'second' =>'secondvalue')
));
```

I'm not using value from database but from an API, at first I want to display this select dropdown on my grid but all I see is a blank space. 
Thanks.

**EDIT :**

[image: Example]

Actually what I need to do is the first row with the dropdown, and the second row is what i get with the code I provided.
I can add a link like the "view" column but it doesn't work for a dropdown

Comment: What are the errors? Does the API actually returns you a result?

Comment: I'm just trying to display the select dropdown, I didn't used the API yet.
The grid is displayed but the "dropdown" column is blank

Comment: Maybe this will help you out : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5190/upgrade-script-create-new-select-attribute-with-options

Comment: What's mentioned in this link is how to add values ( attributes) to a product not how to display a custom dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two ways of doing what you want:

**First way:**

```
$this->addColumn('dropdown', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('dropdown'),
    'filter'    => false,
    'sortable'  => false,
    'index' => 'stores',
    'type' => 'select',
    'values' => array('First'=>'firstvalue', 'second' =>'secondvalue')
));
```

So it will display directly on your grid

**Second way:**

```
$this->addColumn('dropdown', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('dropdown'),
    'filter'    => false,
    'sortable'  => false,
    'index' => 'stores',
    'renderer' => 'Module_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Dropdown',
));
```

Then you need to create a `Dropdown.php` file in `Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\` with :

```
<?php
class Module_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Dropdown extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract{

public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
    $html = '<select>';
    $html .= '<option value="First">First value</option>';
    $html .= '<option value="Second">Second value</option>';
    $html .= '</select>';
    return $html;
  }
}
```

You just have to replace `Module`, `Modulename` with yours and `Dropdown` with what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, why not call your api and save them to the database using an install script [like this one.](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/) 
Then addColumn in your magento grid the usual way ([great tutorial here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-multiselect-and-filter-in-magento-admin-grids-in-and-not-in/)) 
Next, [set up a cron](http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/) to periodically update the information from your api using **[modifyColumn](https://code007.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/adding-modifying-or-dropping-a-column-in-a-table-the-magento-way/)** (minimum every 5mins)

This way you won't have to continuously load from an external api every time you load the page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't do that because, i'm creating an extension and because after each API call, the values can change at any moment

Comment: Okay then, still set up a database column and prefil and update the database with your api data on each call Inside **_addColumnFilterToCollection** using that inchoo.net tutorial. Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for so long with this and then found the [GridControl extension](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl).